# Mvc System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

I need MVC .Net wrapped for Mailchimp API v3.0. So I found this [library](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net).

So when I install this librarly as NuGet package (MailChimp.Net.V3) it also install it's dependencies:
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3
- Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3

The issue is with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3 package. It's installed fine and to my csproj file is added:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

But then when I execute some function from Mailchimp API v3.0 library it's throwing error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be and how to resolve it?

Comment: Double check you don't have any binding redirects in your web.config.